How can I test that the PHP code under test calls the proper method on a trait?
Edit: After reading one of the comments, I realized I misspoke pretty badly in the original post, I've made some edits to clarify. Essentially, I need to check the results but am struggling with that in traits.
I usually use dependency injection (DI), but want to get better with traits since they seem like they can fulfill a similar role while still using composition instead of inheritance. The issue I'm running into is I cannot figure out the best way to make sure that the code under test (CUT) is working as expected when using a trait.
The issue is I'm a bit stuck with how to do this with traits without adding extra code to the actual implementation of the trait.
For example, let's pretend we have a trait:
trait CanLog 
{
    protected function log($level, $message)
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}

class ClassThatWillLog
{
    use CanLog;

    public function foobar()
    {
        // do some stuff
        $this->log("INFO", "I finished successfully!");
    }
}

I want to assert that the log contains some specially formatted INFO level message that also has "I finished successfully". The problem is that I need to inherently make this into an integration test (and check the place the actual CanLog implementation logs to) because I can't currently substitute in the method by which the CanLog trait logs... If that makes sense.
When doing DI, I create an interface and then a test double that implements the interface/contract. You can then check that the fake implementation contains the data it should during the assertion phase. The above could easily be tested using the below:
class FakeLogger implements LoggerInterface 
{
    private array $log = [];

    protected function log($level, $message)
    {
        $this->log[] = "$level: $message\n";
    }

    public function getLogMessages(): array
    {
        return $this->log;
    }
}

class ClassThatWillLog
{
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function foobar()
    {
        // do some stuff
        $this->logger->log("INFO", "I finished successfully!");
    }
}

I could create a similar thing in CanLog as I did in FakeLogger but that feels wrong and adds code that is completely unnecessary for production. I'm just not sure how to replicate the DI equivalent when using a trait instead.

What's the purpose of testing which method is called? You should test the results - that somewhere in a log storage you have a record.

@u_mulder My thought was that I shouldn't be testing the functionality of the CanLog trait which should be independently tested in its own feature test. I just need to confirm that the method gets called properly because then I can assume it works correctly since the trait should already be passing green on its own tests.

You shouldn't be testing whether or not the programmer used composition versus inheritance, you should be testing whether or not a log entry was generated. If you remove the trait completely, and replace the $this->log() call with a locally-defined hard-coded code block that generates the log entry, the test should still pass.

Rereading the question, and some of my other tests, I think I incorrectly described my problem - completely confused myself.
Rather than asserting that the call was made as expected (which is not what I want since mocks do that and those cause you to end up with brittle tests), I need a way to have a fake log that I can check afterwards that it contains the message I expect it to. Just as you said.
The issue is I don't want to check the actual log, which could be in AWS Cloudwatch, the database or some other place which would make this an integration test.

You've described the method already -- build a test double that implements the same interface. The problem here is that you've abandoned the mechanism (i.e., DI) that is perfectly suited for that purpose. If you had a LoggerInterface implemented by AwsLogger and TestLogger concretions, then you could just DI the former in prod and the latter in testing. Or just use Monolog, which already has a nice TestHandler that does exactly what you're describing.

@AlexHowansky I just edited the question to address that I realized I wrote the question completely wrong. Thanks for helping me realize that. I agree DI is perfectly suited for this, I guess my question then should be, when should I use a trait instead of DI? It seems to sit in this strange place between DI and inheritance.

I use traits for cases where I have simple, generic, commonly shared functionality that will never need to be covered by a Strategy Pattern. I think a good litmus test is, anywhere you're tempted to copy/paste. For example, they're especially good for common fields in ORM model definitions that use docblocks/attributes, like in Laravel or Symfony. I have a project where almost every model has lastUpdatedBy and lastUpdatedAt fields, so I just put those properties and their mutators in a trait, and then I don't have to duplicate them in every model.

Traits are "compiler-assisted copy and paste" - once the class is compiled (yes, PHP has a compile stage, don't let anyone tell you otherwise), the code of ClassThatWillLog contains the log method directly in the body. The fact that it came from a trait is completely invisible.
Since it's a protected method, you can override it on child instance, but there's nothing you can do to "recompile" the class with a different trait.
This makes traits a poor choice for this kind of dependency; using an interface and injection is the easy to go.
Traits are useful in the rarer cases where you know that multiple classes will want the same code, but you don't want any relationship between them and you're sure that code will never need to be substituted by a different implementation.
